# Oatmeal Stout, steeped grains 45 min, extract recipe: Should leave in Prim longer than usual before move to Sec?

Tags: secondary-fermentation

Q1: Wondering if since I steeped recipe 4 lbs of various grains to 45 min vs recipe "recommended" 20 min...should I or do I leave in primary carboy for 2 to 3 weeks vs recipe "recommended" 1 week? or is there a FG I should wait for before racking to sec carboy? (OG 1.065)
Q2: Is there a FG I should wait for before bottling?

Comment: Using a secondary is almost never necessary.  It's a holdover from the old days of homebrewing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ No, you should not change your fermentation schedule because of a 20 minute difference in steeping grains. Steeping grains for an extract brew is mostly just extracting flavor and color, but there might be a very small difference in some sugars you get. Regardless, not enough to affect the fermentation in any way.

(You should do a 2 week primary instead of racking to secondary after a week just because it's a better thing to do. Secondary is not necessary for most fermentations.)

2/ You should wait not for a specific FG for bottling, per se, but until the gravity is "terminal" ... not changing for a period of a few days, at whatever gravity that might be. That being said, you can expect your FG to be about 25±5% of your OG, with most yeasts.